# Can't figure out how to do this cocoa binding

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I am a .net developer that's trying to learn how to do cocoa programming on a mac.  I have run into a problem that I can't seem to figure out or find an answer for.

I have created the following classes:

- `ITObject` - subclass of NSObject
- `ITPlayer` - subclass of ITObject
- `ITEnemy` - subclass of ITObject

In my `MainMenu.xib` file I have a window that contains the following controls:

- `NSArrayController` - linked to App Delegate (itObjects)
- `NSTableView` - linked to a NSArrayController (arrangedObjects)
- `NSTextBox` - linked to the same NSArrayController (selection.player)

itObjects is an NSMutableArray that I use to contain any ITObject classes.  The NSArrayController was set to use ITObject as the class.  When I add a ITPlayer to the itObjects property, the text box doesn't read the player property.

The player property is unique to ITPlayer.  If the player property is not part of the class, I want to display '`N/A`' in the text box, if it is there, I want the binding to show the value.  Right now, it does nothing.

More information on the objects:

The code for the items looks like this:

```
@interface ITObject:NSObject <NSCoding>{ 
     int initiativeRoll, initiativeBonus, initiativeKicker;
}
@property int initiativeRoll, initiativeBonus, initiativeKicker;
@property (readonly) int initiativeTotal, initiativeCalc;
@end
```

That is the header file for the ITObject (obviously). The ITEnemy and ITPlayer are setup like this (only so far).

```
@interface ITPLayer:ITOjbect <NSCoding>{
     NSString *player;
}
@property (copy) NSString *player;
@end
```

The init method for the ITPlayer is setup in the implementation file like this:

```
- (void)init{
     self = [super init]
     if (self){
          player = @"undefined";
     }
     return self;
}
```

There is also a initWithCoder: method, but I haven't been using that yet, so I don't think that this is suspect.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Your description is fine. Suggest you include code so it's easier to help you debug.

Comment: There really isn't a lot of code to show.  Most ITObject has a couple of properties, and ITPlayer and ITEnemy have a few more. I would assume this has more to do with my lack of understanding with Cocoa Bindings...and I don't know how to post that, lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I typically do not recommend bindings, and definitely not complicated bindings, to new Cocoa developers. Bindings have the unfortunately situation of tending to "do nothing" when they are the least-bit misconfigured. This makes them very difficult to debug, even for experienced developers. Bindings work very well when dealing with a big page of configuration options tied  to `NSUserDefaults`, but they're a pain to build a complicated UI out of.

That to the side, your setup seems very odd. The owner of `MainMenu.xib` should almost always be a `NSApplication`. Instead of what you're doing, you should drag a new `NSArrayController` onto your XIB and wire it up as you've described, but not make it the file owner.

I would expect that you're seeing exceptions in your log. Probably "`NSArrayController` does not respond to selector `setDelegate:`" or the like. If you're seeing this, it's because the default `MainMenu` nib file is configured to wire the application delegate to the file owner.

---

First, just a little quote from the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingViewTablesWithBindings/PopulatingView-TablesWithBindings.html) to reinforce the point about bindings:

> Populating a view-based table view using Cocoa bindings is considered an advanced topic. While it requires significantly less code (in some cases no code at all), the bindings are hard to see if you are not familiar with the interface. It is sternly suggested that you are comfortable with the techniques for using view-based table views programmatically before you move on to Cocoa bindings.

I love the word "sternly" in this section. After years of development with and without bindings, I tend to avoid them except in the simplest of cases (like preference panels, where they're incredibly useful).

Without bindings, you would follow the instructions in [Populating View-Based Table Views Programmatically](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html). Basically, you will implement `numberOfRowsInTableView:` and (assuming 10.7+) `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`. For each row and column you return a view containing the data you want. This is taken from the iOS way of doing things and is very nice and extremely flexible.

If you need pre-10.7, then things are slightly more complicated, but still more straightforward than bindings. See [Populating Cell-Based Table Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingCellTables/PopulatingCellTables.html). This uses `NSCell` rather than `NSView`. If you just need a simple table displaying string-like data, it's not hard. Just implement `numberOfRowsInTableView:` and `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`. The latter should return something that can be coerced into a string.

If you need a custom `NSCell` for pre-10.7, try it out on your own using the docs, and then you'll probably have some new questions to post.

Comment: You're correct, it's not tied to File's Owner, but rather the 'App Delegate' object that is linked to the AppDelegate class.  Can you point me in the direction to learn how to handle this without using bindings then?

Thank you.

Comment: +1 for avoiding bindings for new developers. I started OS X development when bindings were brand new (10.3?) and it tempted me with the simplicity, but as you say the slightest complexity and it all stops, and as a new developer you've got nowhere to go (no SO in those days!)

Comment: I made the correction in my post to show that the NSArrayController is linked to the App Delegate object in my .xib file.  Everything works just fine except I can't bind to the subclass properties since I have the NSArrayController using the super class (ITOBject).

If anyone can point me to a tutorial or article, or something that can describe another method to do what I want I would really appreciate it.

Comment: This helps a lot, but I think the main problem that I am having (after implementing this) is that I don't understand fully how subclassing works in objective c.  In .net, I can do this: `ITObject myObj = new ITPlayer();`  This would translate to objective c as `ITObject *myObj = [[ITPLayer alloc]init];` but when I send the message to the myObj for the player (like so: `[myObj player]`) string it does nothing.  Is this whole issue I am having caused by my lack of understanding of how subclassing works in objective c?  I understood that what I am trying to do should work.  Thanks

Comment: I'd have to see more of the code. What you've shown here is correct. There's nothing particularly special about subclassing in ObjC, other than it only supports overriding and not overloading. (You cannot have two methods with the same name but different typed arguments.) The most likely error is in your `init` method.

Comment: I will add the code in a new answer so that it can be more easily read.

Comment: I modified the original post with additional information.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but this actually ended up being caused by how I was inserting the objects into my array.  I am not entirely sure of why this works, but if I had it being placed in the array using `[itObjects add:itObject]` it wouldn't work.  When I created a new method: `- (void)insertObject(ITObject *)object inItObjectsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;` everything works perfectly.

Comment: This is because of KVO. "add:" is not a KVC compliant name, so it does not fire any of the bindings when you call it. Search for "Key Value Coding" for details on how you have to name your methods. The naming conventions in Cocoa aren't just for readability. They actually matter at run time.